Need to implement a multi-core multi-threaded multi-SPI bus application with zero interaction between multiple buses on RPi. Guidance?
I need to communicate over 2 different SPI buses to different types of hardware.  I need to be able to pace a high speed write over one bus, while doing a fairly high-volume recurring read on a second bus.  Each bus will be controlled from a different core.  I am worried about how to keep a single driver from causing jitter in the high speed stream.
Can I implement two instances of a driver?  This is going to ideally be on a RPi5.  Should I roll my own driver for each core?  Can the RPI handle this or does the RPi's hardware stream through a common MUX or similar to get to the hardware?
Anybody have a clue?  Actual experience?
I have more than enough processor power, and pins capable of spi bus, but can I make this work?  I have decades of multi-threaded experience.  Will be programming in C/C++.
Theoretical only at this point but need to program ASAP.

For high-volume part you likely need to utilise DMA. For high-speed, better to have a PIO with IRQ affinity to the mostly idling CPU. And depending on the other loads of the system you might have not enough CPU power unless you have an RTOS running on it.
